# mysql 5.6 still records as statement after changing binlog_format to row

Tags: mysql

I ran "set global binlog_format='ROW'" yesterday afternoon, which was STATEMENT before,

```
root@3306 (none)> show variables like '%format%';
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value             |
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| binlog_format            | ROW               |
```

but after checking the binlog, still some sqls logged as statement, for example :

```
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 41498921
#160607 23:17:21 server id 1637  end_log_pos 41499120 CRC32 0xd701f3e2  Query   thread_id=1229089   exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1465312641/*!*/;
**INSERT INTO RECORD (id,shop_id,create_time) VALUES(6014464753,'3','2016-06-07 23:17:21')**
/*!*/;
# at 41499120
#160607 23:17:21 server id 1637  end_log_pos 41499273 CRC32 0xd1840cf1  Query   thread_id=1229089   exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1465312641/*!*/;
UPDATE log SET diamond = diamond + 400 WHERE id = 6014464753
/*!*/;
# at 41499273
```

while others could be logged as ROW,

```
 # at 77950217
#160607 23:38:17 server id 1637  end_log_pos 77950184 CRC32 0x0b0f7620  Rows_query
# **INSERT INTO record (id,shop_id,create_time) VALUES(6001495,'3','*2016-06-07 23:38:17*')**
# at 77950347
#160607 23:38:17 server id 1637  end_log_pos 77950259 CRC32 0x290541ab  Table_map: `test`.`record` mapped to number 1140
# at 77950422
#160607 23:38:17 server id 1637  end_log_pos 77950306 CRC32 0x06774669  Write_rows: table id 1140 flags: STMT_END_F
### INSERT INTO `test`.`record`
### SET
###   @1=6001495 /* INT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @2='3' /* VARSTRING(96) meta=96 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @3='*2016-06-07 23:38:18*' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
# at 77950469
```

it's strange to me, I'm sure the change was done before "160607 23:17:21", but why it's still STATEMENT?
the mysql version is 5.6.24.

BTW: 
the secord sql text is "INSERT INTO record (id,shop_id,create_time) VALUES(6001495,'3','2016-06-07 23:38:17')", but logged
as "@3='2016-06-07 23:38:18'",  why this happens ,the table def is here

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `record` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `shop_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `rech_gif` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `info` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

the 1st question is resolved, since binlog_format is reset dynamically, the new value "row" only affects future connections, the established ones still adopt "statement".
while the 2nd question still there，for "INSERT INTO record (id,shop_id,create_time) VALUES(6001495,'3','2016-06-07 **23:38:17**')", it will be replayed as "INSERT INTO record (id,shop_id,create_time) VALUES(6001495,'3','**2016-06-07 23:38:18**')", which results in inconsistency. When master executed "delete from record where id=6001495", slave just encountered error as can't find the matching record